# Resources$NotFoundException when accessing an attribute as a color

Tags: android, resources

So there I have a color defined as an attribute because it is dependent on the theme.

```
<attr name="primary_text_color" format="color"/>
```

It is defined in the theme as

```
<style name="BaseReferencesTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="primary_text_color">#ffffffff</item>
</style>
```

I'd like to wrap it with a real color resource.

```
<color name="selected_color_normal">?attr/primary_text_color</color>
```

And then read it from code

```
int resolvedColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.selected_color_normal);
```

When I do this, I am getting an exception

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f06010e type #0x2 is not valid
        at android.content.res.Resources.getColor(Resources.java:955)
        at android.content.Context.getColor(Context.java:588)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getColor(ContextCompat.java:523)
```

There are a few modules here I work with:

1. `attr_module` where the attributes are defined.
2. `theme_module` where the theme is defined and set to the application
3. `usage_module` which knows nothing about the theme, but does depend on the `attr_module`.

I know for sure that the theme is applied to the views in the `usage_module`. All the dependencies are set correctly, when I do not try to programmatically read `selected_color_normal`, but just applying the attribute - everything is working.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now I am considering this issue not solvable. Currently my approach is to use `?attr/primary_text_color` and `R.attr.primary_text_color` everywhere possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think, problem here is because `primary_text_color` is attribute, and `selected_color_normal` is color.

Try to make

```
<color name="selected_color_normal">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```

And then, in your style you can give `primary_text_color` value of `selected_color_normal` if needed:

```
<style name="BaseReferencesTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
<item name="primary_text_color">@color/selected_color_normal</item>
```

Comment: I believe that could work, but unfortunately the theme and the `selected_color_normal` are in different modules, so the theme does not know about it.

Comment: I updated my answer and said the same in the comments. You probably need to give it specified colors so that would get rid of the **NotFoundException** error.

Comment: @ArieDov You are trying to access to `selected_color_normal` from other module,  did I properly understand you?

Comment: Let me dig in a bit. I have 3 modules, lets call them `attr module`, `theme module` and `usage module`. Both `theme module` and `usage module` depends on the `attr module`, but none of them know nothing about each other.

The `selected_color_normal` and the code are in the same module.

Comment: @ArieDov oh, its become clear now. It is more difficult, I am not sure that I can help you with this case. Please, update your answer, so people will understand all at once and someone will help you)

Comment: @ArieDov Now I think I got it. You are using `<item` for specifying a color and using it by `?attr`. When you use `R.color.selected_color_normal`, it should directly refer to the specified color but you're referencing the color to **another item in styles** which I believe you cannot get access to it like that. So, specifing a color and directly using it will solve it I hope. however, this is getting pretty complicated.

Comment: @ArieDov just to make it clear, did you include `implementation project(':your_module_name')` in your dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

> `NotFoundException` - Resource ID #0x7f06010e type #0x2 **is not valid**
>
> `#ffffffff`

```
?attr/primary_text_color
```

Might cause the issue. Because you get `NotFoundException` it means that it cannot find the specific color and it only accepts **specified colors** in `<color`.

Comment: This values are here for example purposes. The actual value is valid. 
I don't beleive that would be the case anyway.

Comment: Ohh you're right. This one : `?attr/primary_text_color` has the issue.

Comment: value is valid, after # you can put 8 symbols, then first 2 of them will be for alpha chanel

Comment: Not even close. The attribute is defined in my local module, not in the framework. It is not accessible the way you suggested.

Comment: I missed the `color` part, probably it gets only specified colors ? Also, you get `NotFoundException` which means there is no such thing.

Comment: I do use the theme because I cannot set specific colors instead of attrs by design. If I could - I would. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant make a reference from values/colors to a custom attribute, like this line you mentioned. Because of compile time vs runtime difference.

```
<color name="selected_color_normal">?attr/primary_text_color</color>`
```

Now, you can reference the attribute from code by defining the attribute with the "reference" flag

```
<attr name="primary_text_color" format="color|reference"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To refer to attributes inside data-binding layout XML, you can do:

```xml
<layout>

<data>

  <import type="com.google.android.material.R" />

  <import type="com.google.android.material.color.MaterialColors" />

</data>

...

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Text"
      android:textColor="@{MaterialColors.getColor(textView, R.attr.colorOnBackground)}" />

</layout>
```